# How to create a dataframe from multiple vectors with vector names as levels?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three vectors as:

```
low = c(1,2,3)
med = c(3,5)
high = c(9)
```

I would like to create a dataframe like

```
value group
1     low
2     low
3     low
3     med
5     med
9     high
```

I tried to create a dataframe (or a factor) like `x=data.frame(low = low, med=med, high=high)` but it gives three columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to convert them to a named `list` and then `stack`

```
stack(list(low = low, med = med, high = high))

#  values  ind
#1      1  low
#2      2  low
#3      3  low
#4      3  med
#5      5  med
#6      9 high
```

Comment: greate, just column names are not as desired.

Comment: you can rename them later as needed.. `setNames(stack(list(low = low, med = med, high = high)), c("value", "group"))`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
lst(low, med, high) %>%
    enframe %>% 
    unnest
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  name  value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 low       1
#2 low       2
#3 low       3
#4 med       3
#5 med       5
#6 high      9
```